# TCL lindex removes quotes from list element

Tags: tcl

I have a list where some elements are strings where I need them to be enclosed in quotation marks.

If I iterate over the list and puts each element to the terminal the output looks correct. However, if I lindex to a specific element which is enclosed in quote marks, the quote marks disappear.

Example code:

```
set myList [list "BUILD_PROJ \"I have quotes\""]

foreach element $myList {
    puts [lindex $element 1]    
    puts [lindex $element]    
}
```

Outputs:

```
I have quotes
BUILD_PROJ "I have quotes"
```

How do I get a specific lindexed element from a list to keep its quotation marks?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it seems to be keeping its quotation marks.  I'm away from an environment where I can run Tcl code right now, but maybe you want to escape the escape in your input?  Typically I think this would be done with 3 slashes

Answer (score 0):

My bad, getting mixed up with separators. I think escaping the quotation marks was effectively giving me a list with a single element. Updated to this:

```
set myList [list "BUILD_PROJ" "\"I have quotes\""]

puts $myList
puts [lindex $myList 0]
puts [lindex $myList 1]
```

And now the output is as I expect:

```
BUILD_PROJ {"I have quotes"}
BUILD_PROJ
"I have quotes"
```

Comment: Perhaps tidier to create the list iwth `set myList [list BUILD_PROJ {"I have quotes"}]` -- braces in Tcl are just a quoting mechanism akin to single quotes in sh.

Comment: Thanks, yes, that looks a bit tidier than my version with the escaped quotation marks.